# .Net: Convert Generic List of Objects to DataSet

Tags: .net, generics, dataset

Does anyone have code to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keith Elder](http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2006/03/10/Converting-Generic-Lists-or-Collections-to-a-DataSet.aspx) has an example of this.